# Remove data in React Firebase application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this following code for import user data from Firebase to my React application :

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthUserContext from './AuthUserContext';
import withAuthorization from './withAuthorization';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { config, database, db, auth, itembase, } from 
'../firebase/firebase';

class Collection extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    collection: []
  };

}

//Data from Firebase Database
componentDidMount() {
  var userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const collection = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${userUid}/collection/`)

  collection.on('value', snapshot => {
    this.setState({
      collection: snapshot.val(),
    })
  })
}

//Remove from user collection
removeToCollection(key, e) {
  const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const item = {
    nom: this.state.collection[key].nom,
    parution: this.state.collection[key].parution
  };
  firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection/`).remove(item)

 }

render(){
  const collection= Object.keys(this.state.collection).map(key => {
    return (
      <div key={key}>
        <h3>{this.state.collection[key].nom}</h3>
        <p>{this.state.collection[key].parution}</p>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.removeToCollection.bind(this, key)}>Remove</button> </div>
        )
      });
    return (
      <div>
        {collection}
      </div>
    )
 }

}

const authCondition = (authUser) => !!authUser;

export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(Collection);
```

Like you can see, I have a function for remove data when the user click on the remove button. 
My problem is that when I click the button, I get an error message that appears

[image: Error message]

And here is what my database looks like:

[image: screenshot database]

Thank a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: firebase.database().ref(`/users/${userUid}/collection/`).set(null);

Comment: Hello Shubham Agarwal Bhewanewala and thank you for your help. I did what you told me but now the function delete all the data from "collection" and I would like delete just the data corresponding of the key  of the item collection.

Comment: And I have an error message : "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: I gave you an example of deleting nodes. You should try to look for answer using a suggestion given if it shows some result

Comment: In the ref(put_your_exact_url)..  suppose inside collection of first object you want to delete first element then pass /users/${userUid}/collection/${objectKey}/ to your ref and set it to null and this will do your job

Answer (score 4):

The error comes from:

```
firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection/`).remove(item)
```

It looks like you're trying to pass in the item to remove. That's not how the `remove` method works.

The `remove` method removes all data at the location you call it on. If you pass in a parameter to `remove`, Firebase expects that parameter to be a callback function that it calls after the delete completes (or fails).

So you'll need to create the complete path to the item to remove:

```
let key = "-LlouZxkW1N3Llt6h5nm"
firebase.database().ref(`users/${userUid}/collection/${key}`).remove()
```

If you don't know the key of the item to remove, you will first need to execute a query to find that item and determine its key.

Comment: Hello Frank van Puffelen, thank for your help. I understand better my mistake, but after many test, i don't find how to know the key of the item. I'm totally beginner, so can you tell me more about this subject ?

Comment: You will need to know *something* that identifies the key(s) that you're trying to delete. E.g. if you know the email address of the user, and you want to delete all nodes with that email address, you can query for that email address (something along the lines of `firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo("theemailaddress")`), and delete all resulting nodes.